# JavaFX Clipboard and lostOwnership

Tags: java, javafx, awt

I've been using the Java AWT Clipboard for now, but I noticed that `setContents` is quite slow for a larger number of File-objects.

So, I tried the JavaFX clipboard and it seems to be a lot faster.

But I need to determine when the ownership was lost (`lostOwnership` in `java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner`) e.g. to an external application. But unfortunately the JavaFX clipboard does not seem to provide this functionality at all.

Any ideas on how I could implement this?

Comment: It would probably suit you best to not try to translate `awt` to `JavaFx`. The best thing to do is pretend you know nothing about `awt` and act like you are just learning `JavaFx` for the first time. Do a few `JavaFx` tutorials. Then think about how you can use `JavaFx` ideas to accomplish your mission.

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorials have to do with this, but if you can provide a tutorial that teaches me how to do the same thing as `lostOwnership`, I'm all ears... From what I've gathered, this is simply not implemented in JavaFX, then again I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you missed `The best thing to do is pretend you know nothing about awt` part of the comment.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

Comment: If I was unclear, as I might've been, `lostOwnership` is triggered in AWT, for example, when a user copies e.g. a file to system clipboard in Windows Explorer or other native file manager. I need to act upon such an event. JavaFX does not seem to have a similar "hook"?

Comment: I understand what you said. What I am saying is that if you want to use javafx, you can't think in terms of awt. You have already figured out that javafx does not always implement things like awt does. Given this fact, if you want to use javafx, you need to master how javafx does things. Then you need to solve your programming problems using javafx implementations. As long as you keep lostownership on your mind, you will get no where.

Comment: Try the javafx way. Come back with javafx code and a good question if you run into any problems. I would suggest you start with the posted tutorial to get a better grasp of the ideas associated with javafx and drag and drop.

Comment: But I'm not even doing drag & drop, just basic cut, copy & paste within the system clipboard.

Comment: Well find a tutorial on what you are trying to do.

Comment: With files it may be better to drag and drop instead of cut and paste. I always use drag and drop.